# 2.x html in category urls

Tags: magento2, category

I have a site with multiple websites in a single magento instance.Each website has a different root catalog.

I am trying to generate category urls using this https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

But category urls are generating with two htmls  like the below: brands/crp/collections.html/st-tropaz-collection.html

Can any one please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

Double .html.html prefix solution:

UPDATE `catalog_product_entity_varchar` SET VALUE = REPLACE(VALUE, '.html', '') WHERE attribute_id IN(117, 118, 119, 120);

UPDATE IGNORE `url_rewrite` SET `request_path` = REPLACE(`request_path`, '.html.html', '.html');

After that try to generate urls...

Comment: Thanks for the response.I am getting two htmls in the category urls not in product urls also the two htmls are not at the end like .html.html.I am getting url like brands/crp/collections.html/st-tropaz-collection.html

Comment: This is also solve your issue... i many time face this kind of issue and i solve it using this hack...

Comment: Hello @venki  do you found any solution for this issue.